# Can i make ripple effect in spritekit?

Tags: ios7, xcode5, sprite-kit

I am trying to use ripple effect in spritekit. Here I have written code for ripple  is

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

CATransition *animation=[CATransition animation];
[animation setDelegate:self];
[animation setDuration:1.75];
[animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
[animation setType:@"rippleEffect"];
[animation setFillMode:kCAFillModeRemoved];
animation.endProgress=0.99;

[animation setRemovedOnCompletion:YES];
[self.view.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];
}
```

By using this code when I am touching anywhere in the screen an one wave ripple arise. But I want to make ripple effect specifically on a node. Like 10 radius circle around the touching point on the screen.

Please help.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Core Animation effects work at the level of Core Animation layers, and your Sprite Kit view is one layer regardless of what goes on in terms of scenes and nodes within it.

To apply similar kinds of effects on only a part of the Sprite Kit node hierarchy, you can use the [`SKEffectNode`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKEffectNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013020) class, which can apply a Core Image filter to the results of rendering its child nodes. For animation, you can adjust filter parameters over time in your scene's `update:` method.

The catch to this is that there's no convenient way to use it for a ripple effect, specifically: `CIRippleTransition` is a transition filter, not a single-image-input filter, and you can only use the latter kind with `SKEffectNode`. Varying `CITorusLensDistortion` parameters over time might make a decent substitute, though.